# Naming an excel sheet when saving xslx file using write_xlsx in R

Tags: r, excel

Is there a way to name an excel sheet that's saved in R using `write_xlsx`? I cannot install Java on my computer so `write.xlsx` is not a viable option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it a named list:

```
writexl::write_xlsx(list(sheetname = mydf), path)
```

Comment: I did try it and its the second sentence in the description. What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: Where is the object x?

Comment: `list(sheetname = mydf)`?